# Showing data from different tables with Linq C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can I show data from different tables with linq & C#?
My project is a social network where the user should see all the public posts and the name and the image of the user that post that

For now I have this :

```
 var posts_public = from p in db.Posts
                       join e in db.Privacy on p.id_post equals e.id_post
                       join pu in db.Publish on p.id_post equals pu.id_post
                       join u in db.Users on pu.id_utilizador equals u.id_user
                       where e.id_privacy== 1
                       select new { p.text, u.name,u.image };
Viewbag.post = posts_public;
```

But when I want to show the data that I select show me like this:

```
{ text = ola2, nome = André, image = /Content/Images\IMG_20150616_183508.jpg }
```

And I want that appear just the data like:

```
ola2 
André
IMG_20150616_183508.jpg
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. May I ask why you want this?

Comment: why can't you use the string.Format function inside your linq query where you have `select new { p.text, u.uname, string.Format(@"/Content/Images\{0}", u.image);}`

Comment: And what type of LINQ is this? (Entity Framework?)

Comment: Yeah someone who knows how to spell my name with the accent mark. André. Woot.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry i edit my question. My project is in asp.net, and is a social network where the users can see al the public posts and the name and foto of the user that post that :)

Comment: Well, then I think it's just a display issue, divs and css...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a result class and overload the ToString() method if this is something you are going to be doing all over the place.

Class:

```
public class PublicResult
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", Text, Name, ImagePath); <-- uncomment and delete other return if not using C# 6
        return $"{Text}\n{Name}\n{ImagePath}";
    }
}
```

Then in your query on the select do this:

```
var posts_public = from p in db.Posts
                   join e in db.Privacy on p.id_post equals e.id_post
                   join pu in db.Publish on p.id_post equals pu.id_post
                   join u in db.Users on pu.id_utilizador equals u.id_user
                   where e.id_privacy== 1
                   select new PublicResult{ Text = p.text, Name = u.name, ImagePath = u.image };
```

Now where ever you `Console.WriteLine(posts_public)` it will display as:

```
ola2 
André
IMG_20150616_183508.jpg
```

Or if you are just doing this in a single place just do what I did in the ToString() method where you are outputting this result and not create the class.